# How to get the remote servers host

Tags: php, server, dns, host

I'm trying to determine if a Bing IP is because it is one of their search bots or one of their hosting members. Their name of their host server is Azure and that is what I am trying to find. Bing references [this page](https://mxtoolbox.com/ReverseLookup.aspx) for checking an IP. If you enter the IP 52.167.144.168 on that page you will see it displays Your DNS hosting provider is "Azure". That is what I am trying to get. I've tried many various commands but none return that name. Here is the basic code I am using but I can't find what to do next. Any ideas?

```
    $ip = '52.167.144.168';
    $authns = $addtl = array();
    $domain = gethostbyaddr($ip);

    $result = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_ANY, $authns, $addtl);

    ?><pre><?php
    print_r($result);
    ?></pre><?php?><pre><?php
    print_r($addtl);
    ?></pre><?php?><pre><?php
    print_r($addtl);
    ?></pre><?php
```